# How can I most easily migrate all my apps and settings from one Ubuntu install to another?

Tags: system-installation, configuration, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to migrate user settings and data to new machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25633/how-to-migrate-user-settings-and-data-to-new-machine)

I'll be setting up 10.04 on three computers and don't want to go through and manually download and configure all the same stuff x3, as well as selecting all my Appearance and Windows Manager settings x3.  Surely there's a way to produce a script once I've done the configuring once that I can then run on the second and third computers, thus saving me all that time?