# Installing Ubuntu server on 180 machines - what tool(s) do I have (except clonezilla)

Tags: server, installation, automation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to clone Ubuntu installation (copying to identical hardware)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2724/best-way-to-clone-ubuntu-installation-copying-to-identical-hardware)

I need to install Ubuntu on 180 servers.

Since all are identical hardware, I want to install Ubuntu on a single machine, and clone that image to the rest, and create a post installation script for machine specific settings (e.g. IP Address, etc.).

I wonder what tools are available for such type of operation.