# How can I install ubuntu on pc using vmware image

Tags: vmware, vmdk

I am using win 7.
I have been using VMware for a while, I have installed ubuntu in it.

Now is there any way, I can use this **ubuntu image (vmdk) to install another OS on my pc** parallel to win7

I hope the question is clear.

Comment: You can try cloning http://askubuntu.com/questions/2724/best-way-to-clone-an-installation-copying-to-identical-hardware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by **@Brandon Bertelsen** using clonezilla solved my problem.

> **Detailed Steps**

- you will need vmware workstation, vm player wont work as it does not allow to boot using iso images
- download daemon tool or any similar software
- then download [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org) img
- mount the img downloaded using daemon tool
- use this img mounted in the vmware workstation
- start the vm
- follow the [step by step instructions](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php), now you have a cloned image of the ubuntu which was in the vmware
- now boot your pc (the physical one not the guest in vmware) with the cloned image