# best way to copy your ubuntu to a new hard drive

Tags: 12.04, configuration

I found this question [Best way to clone an installation (copying to identical hardware)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2724/best-way-to-clone-an-installation-copying-to-identical-hardware) to be close to what I need, but I wonder if it is still going to work if, instead of two different machines, I want to clone all to a new hard drive, bigger, and of a different brand (installed on the same machine).

The other option that I was considering is to the do a back-up of the current system and restore it (after a fresh install of the same ubuntu 12.04) on the other hard drive, what do you think?

I am using ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Comment: I looked at that thread, but I was hoping for a simpler way to do it since I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [timeshift](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/timeshift.html) you can backup current OS and then restore it some other computer after installing fresh setup first. it will restore your personal files and installed software

Comment: Thanks Edward, I think this fits!   Do you know if TIMESHIFT is going to copy also the various themes (e.g. gnome)?

Comment: @simplemind please visit the official website and read all the features before proceeding