# tar -cvfz command results in error message unless I omit the hyphen before 'cvfz'

Tags: bash, command-line, tar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sudo tar cvpzf exiting with failure due to previous error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78043/sudo-tar-cvpzf-exiting-with-failure-due-to-previous-error)

When I run the command

```
tar -cvfz backup.tar.gz somedirectory
```

I get the following sterr

```
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

However when I omit the preceding hyphen from `-cvfz` everything seems to work just fine.  Is there a known reason for why the hyphen is preventing me from tar'ing my files?

Comment: What are the previous errors?

Comment: There's no errors before that message, it's some verbose stdout of all the files in that directory

Comment: have you seen this ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/78043/sudo-tar-cvpzf-exiting-with-failure-due-to-previous-error

Comment: Yeah I read that before I posted this question because it didn't mention the hyphen.  Someone mentioned the hyphen on superuser but it was only as an afterthought.  I wanted a more detailed explanation of why including the hyphen causes problems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure why `tar cvfz` works, when accourding to a quick scan of the `man` page and my experience, a hyphen is standard practice. Maybe it's a BSD compatibility thing (like `ps`).

At any rate, your syntax is incorrect. `-f` takes the next argument as the filename to compress to. In this case, that filename is `z`, which isn't what you expected. Here's a sample of the output so you can see what I mean:

```
$ tar -cvfz test.tar.gz scott
tar: test.tar.gz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
scott/
scott/netx/
scott/netx/locks/
scott/netx/locks/netx_running
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

An `ls` shows a file called `z`. The `file` command reveals that it's an uncompressed `tar` archive. It's uncompressed because the `-z` argument wasn't passed. And the error message came from trying to add the non-existant file `test.tar.gz` to the archive.

Simply reorder the options and you'll be OK:

```
tar -czvf test.tar.gz some/directory
```

If you always make the `-f` the last argument, you'll be fine. By the way, remember that short options (one-letter options) that take arguments don't normally require a space between the option and the argument.

**EDIT:** By the way, if the form without the hyphen is a BSD-compatibility thing or something like that, then it's likely that the way that `tar` is invoked in such an environment is different, and doesn't require the `f` flag to specify the input file, but works more like `cp` or something. But this is just speculation based on comparison with `ps` (q.v.).

Comment: You're correct, my syntax was incorrect. Placing the `f` option last did the trick