# How to save theme settings and restore it later?

Tags: 12.04, themes, customization

I have changed base theme and made also some modifications (change fonts, sizes, icons sets etc)

I would like to save all and test some other themes and restore them back.I'm using 12.04.

Is this possible ?

Comment: How about using ubuntu tweak tool, desktop recovery tool will be helpful

Answer (score 5):

I have found a way to save  and restore theme settings. Actually It restores all your personalized settings.

### To Backup

Open a terminal and do this

```
cp ~/.config/dconf/user  ~/settings-backup
cp -r ~/.gconf/apps/metacity ~
```

This will copy the user settings in your home directory in a file named `settings-backup`. The window manager theme (window framing) will be stored in a folder named metacity in the home folder

### To Restore

Open a terminal and do this (I assume your backup file is in your home folder with the name `settings-backup`)

```
cp ~/settings-backup ~/.config/dconf/user
cp -r -v ~/metacity ~/.gconf/apps
```

This will restore the theme  settings and the window manager settings. *(Note that, If you delete a theme, it can't restore that theme)*

Logout and Login again, to see all your settings are restored.

Comment: Is `~/.dconf/user` right? I only found `~/.config/dconf/user`.

Comment: @EricCarvalho yes, you're right. That was a typing error. thanks

Comment: Thanks, I think this will help me. The bounty goes to you.

Answer (score 1):

All your configuration and preferences are store in your /home folder, as a hidden folder. If you backup your home folder you'll be able to restore to your previous configuration. For example, I use Lubuntu 12.04 and have a hidden folder in ~/.config/openbox with some of my system settings.

Related: [How to migrate user settings and data to new machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25633/how-to-migrate-user-settings-and-data-to-new-machine)

Comment: This is too generic. I know I can backup my home folder, or maybe only the dot files, but the OP asks for a way to save the current themes and restore them later. Backing up the whole home folder insn't practical enough, IMHO.