# Before making a clean install, how do I detect configuration changes in the current system?

Tags: system-installation, configuration

I have a five year old Ubuntu system that I've been upgrading, mostly cleanly, but recently there is too much crud in the OS.

*I'm planning to do a clean install to lubuntu 12.10.*

However, I don't want to lose any of my system configuration.  Luckily, `/home` is in its own partition.

I do know most of my configuration changes are in `/etc/` so I will definitely make a backup of that directory.

**Is there any script or tool which will let me detect changes made in the OS configuration directories (essentially, detect if there is a diff) so I can more safely do my clean install.**

I'm sure without it, I could rebuild a system, but it would definitely save me a lot of time if I knew what has changed.

Comment: You may use `dpkg --get-selections > package_list.txt` to list all installed packages but if you migrate to newer Ubuntu version some of them might be not needed anymore.

Comment: @tommyk +1 for a good suggestion - however, I am less worried about what packages are installed: it's the configurations that take a lot of time to get right (bind, fstab, mysql.conf, etc...)

Comment: This does may not help with your current install, but the next time you do an install, mount your `/etc` and `/home` and `/` in separate partitions. The next time you do an install you can retain your etc and home directories

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25633/how-to-migrate-user-settings-and-data-to-new-machine