# Copy of Ubuntu OS from one system to another

Tags: 14.04, windows-7

I have installed OS Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 OS in my laptop which is running well. I have also installed many packages and application in my Ubuntu OS.

Now i am planning to install Ubuntu on my desktop which have Windows XP. Is there any way to copy my Ubuntu 14.04 from my laptop to desktop (without causing any harm to Windows XP) so that i can avoid installing packages and application to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Look here for copying `/home/your-username`: [How to migrate user settings and data to new machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25633/how-to-migrate-user-settings-and-data-to-new-machine)

Look here for transferring packages: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/05/transfer-your-packages-to-a-clean-install/