# Copying settings from Virtual Linux to PC based non virtual linux

Tags: virtualbox, gcc

I am running gcc compiler in virtual linux (all work fine), I would like to have same settings in another PC based Linux. Can anybody tells me what should be copied from the virtual Linux to the new  non virtual Linux? I have put same SW version but so many problems hard to understand.

Comment: Unless you're more precise it's impossible to give an answer. Which settings do you want to copy?

Comment: What ever you installed on the Virtualbox do same on the target system.

Comment: As already said you have to be more specific. In general you could have a look at [how-to-migrate-user-settings-and-data-to-new-machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25633/how-to-migrate-user-settings-and-data-to-new-machine). This should work just the same for a virtual to non-virtual migration